# Mysql 8.0 user defined variables inside triggers not working

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I am using this version of mysql server: image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS books_api_db;
USE books_api_db;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  passwd VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, -- TO DO: obfuscate password 
  email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  access_level ENUM('admin', 'unconfirmed_user') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unconfirmed_user',
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

SET @min_username_length := 5;
SET @min_passwd_length := 5;
SET @min_email_length := 5;

DELIMITER //

-- validate username

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS validate_username_on_insert BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.username) < @min_username_length THEN
    SET @message_text = CONCAT('Username must have a minimum of ', @min_username_length, ' characters.');
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
  END IF;
END//

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS validate_username_on_update BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.username) < @min_username_length THEN
    SET @message_text = CONCAT('Username must have a minimum of ', @min_username_length, ' characters.');
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
  END IF;
END//
```

The problem is that this insert query works without any error:

```
insert into users(username, passwd, email) values ("asd", "asdASD123!@#", "asdasd@asd");
```

The above query should have triggered the validate_username_on_insert trigger and I don't know why

Comment: I tested your code on MySQL 8.0.32, and it returns the error. It works as designed. You must be doing something other than what you show above. For example, if you set the user-defined variables in a different session than the session you do the INSERT, then the variable would not have any value when the trigger fires.

Comment: @BillKarwin you are right. I was dumb enough to not consider that the triggers can't access the variables declared outside of them

Comment: That's not what I wrote, and in fact it's not true. Triggers _can_ read user-defined variables set in the session before the trigger. But any user-defined variable exists only in the session where it is set. If you close and open a new connection, any user-defined variables are reset.

Comment: I needed to define them once, when the server started, and I've expected them to work whenever anyone connected after. So when someone connected after server instantiation, the user defined variables were null for that connection/session. Thanks for clarification

Comment: Sorry for the unnecessary notification due to my previous reply. The code is working perfectly for me too. MySQL 8.0.30